# StringBuilder.AppendFormat double quote issue

Tags: c#, string, double-quotes

I want to build a string with content of some xml nodes, like

```
StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();
xmlString.AppendFormat("<Product Name=\"{0}\">", name);
```

But the result I got by calling xmlString.ToString() is

```
<Product Name=\"ABC\">
```

What I expect is

```
<Product Name="ABC">
```

Does anyone know how can I do that? Or is there any other proper way of escaping the double quote for StringBuilder.AppendFormat()?

Comment: Why are you using `StringBuilder` for this? You should be using a proper XML library to ensure that the XML you generate is valid.

Comment: is it writing to file like that, or are you viewing the result of xmlstring in memory? because that would show you the escaped quote mark to let you know it's there.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it worked fine for me. Maybe show us more to see if we can see another problem.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly fine for me, there's something missing here.

Answer (score 10):

How do you know that is what you got?

My guess is that you looked in the debugger, which shows escaped quotes ( \" ).

Try `Console.Out.WriteLine(xmlString.ToString());`

Comment: Yes, you are write. It shows correctly in the Console winidow. Thanks!